Why can the deployment be updated successfully after the ResourceVersion is set to ""?
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
)

func main() {
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", "path_to_kubeconfig")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    aiClient, err := aiclient.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    deploymentsClient := clientset.AppsV1().Deployments("kube-system")
    deployment, err := deploymentsClient.Get(context.TODO(), "coredns", metav1.GetOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    deployment.ResourceVersion = ""
    replicas := int32(3)
    deployment.Spec.Replicas = &replicas

    _, err = deploymentsClient.Update(context.TODO(), deployment, metav1.UpdateOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}


Why can the deployment be updated successfully after the ResourceVersion is set to ""?
But it doesn't work for custom resources? The error is as follows:
xxx is invalid: metadata.resourceVersion: Invalid value: 0x0: must be specified for an update


I want to know what special processing k8s does for deployment? For example, assigning a value to resourceVersion? Where can I find this in the source code?

When modifying custom resources, oldTask.ResourceVersion = "" will get an error:
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"

    aiclient "ai/aiops-engine/pkg/generated/clientset/versioned"
)

func main() {
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", "path_to_kubeconfig")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    aiClient, err := aiclient.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    oldTask, err := aiClient.AiV1alpha1().TrainingTasks("default").Get(context.TODO(), "task1", metav1.GetOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    
    oldTask.ResourceVersion = "" 
    oldTask.Spec.Alias = "foo" // modify anything
    
    task, err := aiClient.AiV1alpha1().TrainingTasks("default").Update(context.TODO(), oldTask, metav1.UpdateOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error()) // <- metadata.resourceVersion: Invalid value: 0x0: must be specified for an update
    }
}


The code snippet shows the update of a deployment which you say works, can you add the part that fails? (Custom resource)
It would also be interesting to know exactly where an error is thrown.

Thanks, I have edited the question and added the code. Because the custom resource client is generated by k8s.io/code-generator, you may not be able to run the code directly, but any CRD should behave the same.

Can you try setting ResourceVersion to null instead?
